# Math.Round() Decimal Incorrect value

Tags: math, decimal, rounding

I have goggled and tried a-lot of different things none work. They are provide the same incorrect value.

**WRONG**

- ex VAT: £8.33 VAT: £1.67 Total: £9.99

**RIGHT**

- ex VAT: £24.99 VAT: £5.00 Total: £29.99
- ex VAT: £70.83 VAT: £14.17 Total: £85.00
- ex VAT: £16.66 VAT: £3.33 Total: £19.99

**Code to work out VAT**

```
            **VAT = 1.2**

            var totalVat = orderLine.MixPrice - (orderLine.MixPrice / orderLine.VatPerItem);
            var priceMinusVat = orderLine.MixPrice - totalVat;
```

**What I have tried**

```
var roundPriceMinusVat = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(priceMinusVat), 2);
var roundTotalVat = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(totalVat), 2);

var roundPriceMinusVat = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(priceMinusVat), 3);
var roundTotalVat = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(totalVat), 3);

var roundPriceMinusVat = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(priceMinusVat), 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
var roundTotalVat = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(totalVat), 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

I know technically it is right however as this is customer facing I know someone will work it out with a calculator and email saying "this is wrong it doesn't add up".

I don't really know what to do?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Clare

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Perhaps you shouldn't be using floating point math if the rounding involved leads to issues. At the very least, don't round *everything* - do your calculations with full precision, and only round for display purposes...

Comment: Kevin: C#

Twalberg: i am only rounding for display purposes.

The issue seems to be with 9.99 - (9.99, 1.2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the true values are 9.99/1.2=8.325 and 9.99-(9.99/1.2)=1.665. Rounding both up will result in a surplus of 0.005+0.005=0.01. Compute

Compute the tax first, decide on rounding up or down and round the tax, then subtract from price with tax.

Comment: What is left is to compute the tax in a way satisfactory to the taxing agency!